# In Symfony2, how do I expire a user's account?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to give to an user a ROLE for a time limited. For example, if I have three roles:

1. ROLE_ADMIN
2. ROLE_ACTIVE
3. ROLE_USER

When a user is created he become with the **ROLE_ACTIVE** account, he has 30 days to use the account, then he become the **ROLE_USER.**

I have seen the `credentials_expire_at` in the user entity, but how do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `credentialsExpiresAt` like:

```
$user = new User(); // depends on your user class name
$user->setCredentialsExpireAt(new \DateTime()); // expires now for example
```

This only solves part of your problem as once the Date has passed the `setCredentialsExpireAt` date the user wont be able to login anymore as their login has expired.

You could tackle this issue a number of ways, maybe run a cronjob that looks for expired users with the ROLE_ACTIVE role and changes their ROLE and re-activates the account.

Or this other option may work better for your situation:

Override the following method in the [User Model](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php):

```
//  FOSUserBundle/Model/User.php - override this in your child bundle.
public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
{
    if (true === $this->credentialsExpired) {
        return false;
    }
    if (null !== $this->credentialsExpireAt && $this->credentialsExpireAt->getTimestamp() < time()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In this if block:

```
if (null !== $this->credentialsExpireAt && $this->credentialsExpireAt->getTimestamp() < time()) {
```

Replace the `return false` with logic to change the users role if they have ROLE_ACTIVE, remove the expiry and reactivate the account. Save the user details and `return true`.

Basically this should mean that when the user logs in and the FOSUserBundle checks to see if the account has expired, you will have an opportunity to override the expiration and make the required changes before the user is denied access, You will still need to set the `credentialsExpireAt` on account creation.

**EDIT:**

For your particular use case I think it would be a good idea to set the credentialsExpiresAt field to now + 30 days globally. You can do this in your User Entity, Which when using FOSUserBundle.. you are required to extend.

```
// Your file that extends FOSUserBundle/Model/User.php
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setCredentialsExpireAt(
        new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+30 days")))
    );
}
```

With this code in place every new user's credentials will expire within 30 days, in which your code will have an opportunity to catch the event and override whatever you need.

Comment: thanks for you answer. I think this is exactly what I need, I tried this, but in the first part of your answer, where have I to declare the new User object? In a controller, but which one?

Comment: That's an very easy solution, thanks a lot. The only problem is that the user will not be able to log anymore, even with ROLE_USER rights...

Comment: That is why you override the `isCredentialsNonExpired` method. this is the method which will check if a user has expired by checking the credentialsExpireAt field. so you check to see if they have passed this date, upgrade them to ROLE_USER and clear the credentialsExpireAt. If ALL new users are created this way and you use this code they will be upgraded automatically to ROLE_USER and credentialsExpireAt cleared. They should never be able to not login

Comment: Perfect, this work fine.

if (null !== $this->credentialsExpireAt && $this->credentialsExpireAt->getTimestamp() < time()) {
            $this->removeRole('ROLE_ACTIVE');
            $this->addRole('ROLE_USER');
            $this->setCredentialsExpireAt(NULL);
            return true;
        }

Comment: great, dont forget to save your changes in there

Comment: When you make changes to your user, as in `$this->setCredentialsExpireAt(NULL);` you need to save the changes afterwards to make the changes permanent. otherwise it will keep resetting every time they login